# php dynamic table page content based on url

Tags: php, sql, ajax

i'm developing site to show car parts/accessories in table format.

My question is If user search accessories.com/**car name**, the table content only show that particular **car name** accessories/parts only.
How to get a **car name** from URL and add dynamically to the query.

projctfile/index.php

```
$url='accessories.com/tesla3';
$r = parse_url($url);

$path = explode('/',$r['path']);

echo $path[1];
```

it return page not found error.

Comment: You need to do some research and make some attempts yourself first. If you get stuck on something _specific_ with your code along the way, come back, show us what you've tried, the expected result and what results you're getting.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php however you should probably start with a basic PHP tutorial before getting variables from a client and connecting that to a DB.

Comment: I get what you're trying to do, but as stated, you need to do some research and make some attempts yourself first. We're here to help you sort out specific issues with your code, but we're not here to write it all for you, which a proper answer to your current question (it's not even a real question) would require.

Comment: Redirect all queries to index.php via .htacces mod rewrite in Apache or someway in httpd.conf if you’re using nginx, then find the URL part with something like `explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`.

Comment: please explain more clear your question with picture??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re using Apache, put this into .htaccess file in your folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" "index.php"
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html